# Why do cin and getline exhibit different reading behavior?

Tags: c++, whitespace, iostream, cin, getline

For reference I have already looked at [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

I want to understand cin and getline behavior. I am imagining cin and getline to be implemented with a loop over the input buffer, each iteration incrementing a cursor. Once the current element of the input buffer equals some "stopping" value (" " or "\n" for cin, "\n" for getline), the loop breaks.

The question I have is the difference between the reading behavior of cin and getline. With cin, it seems to stop at "\n", but it will increment the cursor before breaking from the loop. For example,

```
string a, b;
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
cout << a << "-" << b << endl;
// Input: "cat\nhat"
// Output: "cat-hat"
```

So in the above code, the first cin read up until the "\n". once it hit that "\n", it increments the cursor to the next position "h" before breaking the loop. Then, the next cin operation starts reading from "h". This allows the next cin to actually process characters instead of just breaking.

When getline is mixed with cin, this is not the behavior.

```
string a, b;
cin >> a;
getline(cin, b);
cout << a << "-" << b << endl;

// Input: "cat\nhat"
// Output: "cat-"
```

In this example, the cin reads up to the "\n". But when getline starts reading, it seems to be reading from the "\n" instead of the "h". This means that the cursor did not advance to "h". So the getline processed the "\n" and advances the cursor to the "h" but does not actually save the getline to "b".

So in one example, cin seems to advance the cursor at "\n", whereas in another example, it does not. getline also exhibits different behaviors. For example

```
string a, b;
getline(cin, a);
getline(cin, b);
cout << a << "-" << b << endl;

// Input: "cat\nhat"
// Output: "cat-hat"
```

Now getline actually advances the cursor on the "\n". Why is there different behavior and what is the actual implementation of cin vs getline when it comes to delimeter characters?

Comment: "So in one example, cin seems to advance the cursor at "\n", whereas in another example, it does not." No, it does not in either case. Reading from `cin` using `operator>>`, by default, skips **leading** whitespace, not trailing whitespace. As your account is over 8 years old and you have multiple gold badges, you should understand by now the [expectation for research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Questions like this one are [easily answered](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cin+whitespace) with a search engine.

Comment: Oh interesting. But if cin is able to distinguish between leading and trailing "\n", then why doesn't getline skip leading "\n"

Comment: `cin` and `getline()` do not exhibit different behaviour. Both `getline()` and formatted extraction (using operator `<<`) interact with the stream, and what you are seeing is that they interact with `cin` (and any stream) differently. They do that because they are specified differently.  `operator<<()` skips white space, reads the value (if it can), and stops when it reaches whitespace.   `getline()` (by default) keeps reading until it encounters a newline - and discards the newline.  Using them both together can cause unexpected interactions with some user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> reading behavior of cin and getline.

`cin` does not "read" anything. `cin` is an input stream. `cin` is getting read ***from***. `getline` reads from an input stream. The formatted extraction operator, `>>`, reads from an input stream. What's doing the reading is `>>` and `std::getline`. `std::cin` does no reading of its own. It's what's being read ***from***.

> first cin read up until the "\n". once it hit that "\n", it increments the
> cursor to the next position

No it doesn't. The first `>>` operator reads up until the `\n`, but ***does not read it***. `\n` remains unread.

The second `>>` operator starts reading with the newline character. The `>>` operator skips all whitespace in the input stream ***before*** it extracts the expected value.

The detail that you're missing is that `>>` skips whitespace (if there is any) ***before*** it extracts the value from the input stream, and not ***after***.

Now, it is certainly possible that `>>` finds no whitespace in the input stream before extracting the formatted value. If `>>` is tasked with extracting an `int`, and the input stream has just been opened and it's at the beginning of the file, and the first character in the file is a `1`, well, the `>>` just doesn't skip any whitespace at all.

Finally, `std::getline` does not skip any whitespace, it just reads from the input stream until it reads a `\n` (or reaching the end of the input stream).

Comment: Right but thats my confusion. If ">>" reads until "\n" but doesn't read "\n", then that means subsequent uses of  ">>"  must be skipping leading "\n". Otherwise the cursor would be stuck at "\n". But getline doesn't seem to be skipping LEADING "\n" (newline, not whitespace). So getline reads the "\n" but then stops. So subsequent getline operations start reading from the actual characters.

Comment: Your understanding is accurate. `\n` is considered whitespace, and everything in my answer is consistent with your comment. What led you to expect that `std::getline` skips leading whitespace? It doesn't, of course. `>>` skips whitespace, `getline` does not. They are different functions. They do different things. That's why they exist: they do different things.

Comment: @JeremyFisher • a newline **is** whitespace.

Comment: @Eljay that was my confusion. I didn't consider "\n" whitespace. "\n" to me is just a special character representing "go to the next line". "whitespace" to me meant " "

Comment: @SamVarshavchik one thing then, if getline doesn't skip leading whitespace, why do 2 back to back getline operations read the lines successfully? Wouldn't the first getline operation read the characters up to "\n" but then the 2nd would read the "\n" and stop?

Comment: No, `getline` reads the `\n`, it just doesn't put it into the `std::string`. `std::getline` reads up to ***and including*** the next `\n`, and puts everything it reads, ***except*** the newline into the string.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @JeremyFisher • The [whitespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) characters: `\t \n \v \f \r` and space.

Comment: The term "whitespace" includes space characters, newline, vertical and horizontal tab, form feed, carriage return, and backspace.    `std::isspace('\n')` and `std::isspace(' ')` both return a non-zero value.

Comment: When I try the code and the same input, both `getline()` and `>>` don't treat \n as a whitespace character and just wait for me to input another string, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr: it's because how `std::cin` is intra-line-oriented while  getline is line-oriented.

Historically, in C's standard library, we had the functions `scanf()` and `getline()`:

- When you tell `scanf()` to expect a string, it

  > ...  stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

  and more generally,

  > Most conversions [e.g. readings of strings] discard initial white space characters

  (from the [`scanf()` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html))
- When you call `getline()`, it:

  > reads an entire line ... the buffer containing the text ... includes the newline character, if one was found.

  (from the [`getline()` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html))

Now, C++'s `std::cin` mechanism replaced `scanf()` for formatted input matching, but with type safety. (Actually `std::cin` and `std::cout` are quite problematic as replacements, but never mind that now.) As a substitute for `scanf()`, it inherits many of its features, including being averse to picking up white space.

Thus, just like `scanf()`, running `std::cin >> a` for a string `a` will stop before a `\n` character, and keep that line break in the input stream for future use. Also, just like `scanf()`, `std::cin`'s >> operator skips leading whitespace, so if you use it a second time, the `\n` will be skipped, and the next string picked up starting from the next line's first non-whitespace character.

With `std::getline()`, you get the exact same `getline()` behavior of decades past.

---

<sub>PS - you can control the whitespace-skipping behavior using the [skipws format-flag](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags) of `std::cin`</sub>

Comment: this is a good answer as well. One question - if I had a string with a bunch of newlines, like "test string\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n second line", would 2 getlines back to back read the strings properly? Because first getline should read all the "\n" to " " before "second line"?

Comment: @JeremyFisher: You would need as many getline's as you have `\n`'s, since those consecutive `\n` designate ends of empty lines. An empty line is a line. Anyway, consult the man page or, for the C++ version, the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).